# .NET 4.0 & CrystalReports

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-4.0, crystal-reports

I have a dll build with target framework 3.5 that manage reports; this dll use the version 10.5.3700.0 of CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine

Now, I have created a new wpf application based on .NET framework 4.0 and I added the report dll reference to project.

I had to install the Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010 library (http://www.businessobjects.com/jump/xi/crvs2010/default.asp) to build the application without errors...now it builds success, but the report print don't work.

It's generate an error when set datasource...the message is:

> Unknown Query Engine Error
>   Error in File C:\DOCUME~1\oli15\IMPOST~1\Temp\MyReport {4E514D0E-FC2C-4440-9B3C-11D2CA74895A}.rpt:
>   ...
>    Source=Analysis Server
>          ErrorCode=-2147482942
>          StackTrace:
>               at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.DatabaseControllerClass.ReplaceConnection(Object oldConnection, Object newConnection, Object parameterFields, Object crDBOptionUseDefault)
>               at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table.SetDataSource(Object val, Type type)
>               at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.SetDataSourceInternal(Object val, Type type)

I think that it use a different version reference for CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, it's possible?

How can tell it to use the 10.5.3700.0 version?

Comment: The problem is method ReportDocument.SetDataSource; if I switch my application to framework 3.5 it work, if I use framework 4.0 it generate a report exception. Why?!?!?

Comment: I solve. I set "useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy" to true the attribute of app.config startup tag and it works.

Answer (score 0):

For persons using this in Managed C++, the solutions posted in the comments are only part of the solution. I've also applied what is stated on http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/WorkingWithConfigFiles.aspx after some days of desperation, and now I am happy to look to my projects working on wheels :)